# Is cl-opengl glut mature?

Tags: opengl, lisp, common-lisp

I want to create my own editor to code in, at first I was going to use ncurses to make a terminal editor. Not working, the library has no documentation and it's mail list is completely empty. I'm probably going to make it with a gui library instead. I'm thinking of just using glut from cl-opengl, but I can't find any info on how developed it is. If it's not in a good usable state I guess I'll just use gtk.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use [lispbuilder](http://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/). It's by far more complete than cl-opengl.

But if you want a gui library for lisp you can try [wxcl](http://www.wxcl-project.org/).

Comment: Lispbuilder is an excellent lispy wrapper around SDL which itself provides good tools for making an opengl context. I'm not sure how the projects were at the time but nowadays cl-opengl provides probably the best maintained wrapper around the OpenGl api itself. So using lispbuilder with cl-opengl is very recommendable.